# changing the index according to click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, indexing

I'm trying to make an image play each time i click it, i have two songs and two images at the moment.
every time i click an image only one of the songs play because the index is 0 right now. 
I want a different song to play according to the image i'm clicking (i might add more pictures in the future so i was looking for a solution that doesn't involve changing the JS).
is there anything i can write in the index (instead of 0) that would change according to the image i'm clicking?

HTML:

```
<section id="imgsound">
<div class="imageCircle">
    <div id="bird">
        <img id="birdImg" class="circle" src="images/bird.jpg">
        <audio id="birdAudio" class="audio"><source src="sounds/bird.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="imageCircle">
    <div id="stream">
        <img id="streamImg" class="circle" src="images/stream.jpg">
        <audio id="birdAudio" class="audio"><source src="sounds/stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">   </audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var audio;
function playAudio(){
    if (audio == false){
        $(this).css({"transform":"rotate(-360deg)"});
        $(".audio")[0].play();
        audio = true;
    }else{
        $(this).css({"transform":"rotate(360deg)"});
        $(".audio")[0].pause();
        audio = false;
    }
}
$(".imageCircle").click(playAudio);
```

Comment: what happens if you change this `$(".audio")[0].play();` into this: `$(this).find(".audio")[0].play();`

Comment: fyi: you can replace `if (audio == false)`  with `if (!audio)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for the audio element *relative* to the clicked image, rather than searching for it via a global selector. We can do this with something like `siblings()`, filtering on audio elements only.

We can also truncate and simplify the code.

```
let audio;
function playAudio() {
    $(this).css({"transform":"rotate("+(!audio ? -360 : 360)+"deg)"});
    $(this).siblings('audio')[!audio ? 'play' : 'pause']();
    audio = !audio;
}
$(".imageCircle").click(playAudio);
```

If you're not confident that the `audio` element would always be a sibling of the `img` element, you could go up to the `.imageCircle` ancestor and look within that.

```
    $(this).closest('.imageCircle').find('audio')[!audio ? 'play' : 'pause']();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consult [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) for this. With it, you can get information of the element, that triggered the event. For example you can get the id or other attributes of the node from it.